# Display cursor pointed line in textbox and hide other lines in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Is there any method to display only single line of textfile which is loaded in textbox when cursor/key up & down is done and hide other lines while current line is highlighted.

Example:
Two lines of textfile in textbox are:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06BQM.png)

> abcdef
>
> 1234

When cursor is pointed on line containing ***abcdef***, then line containing ***1234*** which is second line of textfile should hide and when cursor is on second line then first and other lines of textbox should hide.

[sample output of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06BQM.png)

Comment: Can you please provide the parts of your code where you have problems achieving that behaviour?

Comment: i am not able to get logic only to implement this type of behaviour

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site. What you want to do is not especially difficult so you need to give it some thought and do the appropriate research. If you encounter a specific problem along the way, that would be the time to post a question here.

Comment: so what is the use of stackoverflow? if there are such talented guys over here who can do any coding work then if someone says not getting any idea to do the behaviour work then there should be some responsible guy who can help with the code for my idea as i am not getting the solution for the idea.